# change horizontal navigation to vertical

Tags: html, css

I have horizontal navigation bar like this.
[image]

I need to make this navigation bar vertical left. This is my html

```
<div ng-controller="PortalController">
    <header>
        <h1>E_Zuite</h1>
        <nav role='navigation'>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="link-1 entypo-home active" href="#home"></a></li>
                <li><a class="link-2 entypo-picture" href="#clients"></a></li>
                <li><a class="link-3 entypo-user" href="#about"></a></li>
                <li><a class="link-4 entypo-mail" href="#contact-us"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

and this is my css

```
 header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #373948;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}

header h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Meddon', cursive;
}

header nav ul {
  height: 70px;
  float: right;
}

header nav ul li {
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I exactly need this navigation bar and icons from top.I'm not much familiar with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css to this:

```
header {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #373948;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}

header h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Meddon', cursive;
}

header nav ul {
  height: 70px;
  float: right;
}

header nav ul li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

What I have done is simple, changed the width of the `header` and set the height to be `100%`, then I have set the `width` and `float` attribute for your `li` menu.

It should work as you expect, BUT have a look through it to make it exactly how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

```
header h1{
  float:none;
 }
header nav ul {
  float:none;
 }
header nav ul li{
 display:block;
 width:100%
}
```

just add css in your css file.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to fix your vertical nav to the left, the code below will help.

```
 nav{
      position: fixed;//fixes the navigation bar to left 
      top: 100px;
      left: 0px;    
    }
    header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 70px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: #373948;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    }

    header h1 {
      float: left;
      margin: 5px 0px;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Meddon', cursive;
    }

    header nav ul {
      height: 70px;
      width: 30px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    header nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 30px;
    }
```